# Refreshing the order of an ordered list, after appending a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5NrpP/)

I'm attempting to use an `ol` to display several, dynamic, list items. Upon `appending` a list item using jQuery, I'd have hoped that the browser would've refreshed the ordered list, however it doesn't appear to be.

```
<ol>
    <li value="1">First</li>
    <li value="2">Second</li>
    <li value="4">Forth</li>
</ol>
```

After appending `<li value="3">Third</li>`, the resulting order is:

```
// First
// Second
// Forth
// Third <-
```

Do I need to trigger a re-order, or is the order only calculated upon rendering the page / adding the list DOM element?

*Note: I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95m*

Comment: I don't think the browser ever orders a list -- see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q89hG). You can use [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VdrDD), though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener - to be honest, it'll be easier to trigger the sort yourself after adding the item.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that `value` is not a valid attribute of `li`, so your code is invalid. You should use a `data` attribute for any non-standard attributes you require, the you need to write a sorter function. Try this:

```
$('#addThird').one('click', function() {
   $('ol').append('<li data-value="3">Third</li>');
    sortItems();
});

var sortItems = function() {
    var $items = $('ol li');
    $items.sort(function(a, b) {
        var keyA = $(a).data('value');
        var keyB = $(b).data('value');
        return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    $.each($items, function(index, row){
        $('ol').append(row);
    });
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NrpP/5/)

This sorts by the `data-value` attribute of the element, but that can be amended as required.